# Entire np array changed when one value is altered

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, object

I'm trying to create a numpy array of objects called locusts, which are an instance of a class called locust. The locust object has a property called 'group' which can be 0 or 1. I create the array with `np.full` and then attempt to loop through half of the locusts and set their group to zero, and then set the groups of the other half to 1, like so:

```
    locusts = np.full((numrows,N), locust(grid[0][0],0))   
    for i in range(numrows):
        for c in range(C):
            x = int(np.random.uniform()*len(grid[i]))
            placec = grid[i][x]
            print(placec.location)
            locusts[i, c].place=placec
            locusts[i, c].group=0
            placec.newlocust()
            print(i,c,[x.group for x in locusts[i]])
        for g in range(C, C+G):
            x = int(np.random.uniform()*len(grid[i]))
            placeg = grid[i][x]
            locusts[i, g].place=placeg
            locusts[i, g].group=1
            placeg.newlocust()
            print(i,g,[x.group for x in locusts[i]])
```

When I run this, however, the following prints:

```
0 0 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0 1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0 2 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0 3 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0 4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0 5 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
0 6 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
0 7 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
0 8 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
0 9 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

It seems like the entire list is being changed each iteration of the loop.  Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: `np.full` assigns that one `locust` object to all element of the array: `locust(grid[0][0],0)`.  It does not assign a copy, or make a separate object for each slot.  For this reason `full` should not be used when making an object dtype array.

Comment: A list or list of lists might be better than an object dtype array.  But you'd get the same problem creating a list filled with the one object, `alist = [locust(...)]*10`.  Instead use `alist = [locust(...) for _ in range(10)]`.  Lists should be faster.

Comment: Does this `locust` class do anything significant?  If they just hold a couple of values, you might be better off with a couple of numeric arrays, or a structured arrays.  `numpy` isn't particularly 'friendly' to OOP style programming.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj np.full was the problem. I fixed it by making a python array and converting it to an np array